# How to navigate to next page in selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm a fresher in this field. So I'm trying to navigate to a web page to scrape a data, when I execute the code, its scrapes the 1st page data but never navigates to the next pages. I have tried in a many ways but I couldn't find. Please check below my code I have written a code for pagination. please anyone help me on this. thanks in advance

```
import xlwt
from selenium import webdriver
import re
import time
from datetime import date
class kotsovolosmobiles:
    def __init__(self):
        self.url='https://www.kotsovolos.gr/mobile-phones-gps/mobile-phones/smartphones?pageSize=60'
        self.country='GR'
        self.currency='euro'
        self.VAT= 'Included'
        self.shipping = 'Available for shipment'
        self.Pre_PromotionPrice ='N/A'
    def kotsovolos(self):
        
        wb = xlwt.Workbook()
        ws = wb.add_sheet('Sheet1',cell_overwrite_ok=True)
        ws.write(0,0,"Product_Url")
        ws.write(0,0,"Product_Manufacturer")
        ws.write(0,1,"Product_Url")
        ws.write(0,2,"Product_Price")
        ws.write(0,3,"Product_Model")
        ws.write(0,4,"Memory")
        ws.write(0,5,"Currency")
        ws.write(0,6,"Color")
        ws.write(0,7,"VAT")
        ws.write(0,8,"Shipping Cost")
        ws.write(0,9,"Pre-PromotionPrice")
        ws.write(0,10,"Country")
        ws.write(0,11,"Date")
        ws.write(0,12,"Raw_Model")
        wb.save(r"C:\Users\Karthick R\Desktop\VS code\kotsovolos.xls")
        driver=webdriver.Chrome()            
        driver.get(self.url)
        today = date.today()
        time.sleep(5)
        cookies = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a[id="CybotCookiebotDialogBodyLevelButtonLevelOptinAllowAll"]')
        cookies.click()
        print("cookies accepted")
        driver.maximize_window() 
        time.sleep(5)
        titles = []
        models = []
        memorys = []
        prod_prices = []
        p_links =[]
        p_colors = []
        while True:
            storage_box = []
            storage_box = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div[class="product"]')
            for storage_boxes in storage_box:
                product_url = storage_boxes.find_element_by_css_selector('div[class="title"] a').get_attribute('href')
                print(product_url)
                p_links.append(product_url)

                p_model = storage_boxes.find_element_by_css_selector('div[class="title"] a').text
                print(p_model)
                models.append(p_model)

                manufacturer1 = p_model.split(" ")
                print(manufacturer1[0])
                titles.append(manufacturer1[0])

                memory = []
                memory = re.findall('\d+ ?[gG][bB]',p_model)
                print(memory)
                memory1 = str(memory).replace("['",'').replace("']",'').replace("[]",'').strip()
                if "," in memory1:
                    arr=memory1.split(",")
                    for str1 in arr:
                        str2=str1.replace("GB", "").replace("gb", "").replace("'", "").strip() 
                        if len(str2)!=1: 
                            memory_str=str1
                            break 
                elif (memory1 == ""):
                    memory_str ='N/A'
                else:
                    memory_str=memory1 
                memory_str = memory_str.replace("'", "").strip() 
                print(memory_str)
                memorys.append(memory_str)

                colors= []
                prod_color = p_model.split(" ")
                length = len(prod_color)
                indexcolor = length-3 
                colors.append(prod_color[indexcolor])
                color1 = str(colors).replace("['",'').replace("']",'').strip()
                print(color1)
                p_colors.append(color1)

                p_price = storage_boxes.find_element_by_css_selector('.priceWithVat > .price').text
                print(p_price)
                prod_prices.append(p_price)
 
            next = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.pagination_next a')
            time.sleep(3)
            next.click()
            print("next page") 
            time.sleep(3)

kotsovolos_gr = kotsovolosmobiles()
kotsovolos_gr.kotsovolos()
```

Comment: https://www.kotsovolos.gr/mobile-phones-gps/mobile-phones/smartphones?page=1 and https://www.kotsovolos.gr/mobile-phones-gps/mobile-phones/smartphones?page=2 shows you two different content ?

Comment: nope, it shows same content

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the page isn't loaded yet, try to replace the last block in the loop by

```
next = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.pagination_next a')
url = next.get_attribute('href')
driver.get(url)
sleep(3) # Maybe it's not necessary
```

Comment: I tried your answer but again I'm getting the same problem the code is not navigates to next page. I don't know where I did a mistake.

Comment: Try to open the python shell and do the code line by line, then you could see what's happen, in the terminal type python (or python3, in some cases), when the shell is running import the necessary as

`from selenium import webdriver` and go directly to what you want to see, so 

`driver=webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://www.kotsovolos.gr/mobile-phones-gps/mobile-phones/smartphones?pageSize=60')` then run my code above (and below also)

`next = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.pagination_next a')

url = next.get_attribute('href')

driver.get(url)`

Answer (score 0):

Try like below. I was able to visit all the other 5 pages.

```
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get("https://www.kotsovolos.gr/mobile-phones-gps/mobile-phones/smartphones?pageSize=60")
time.sleep(5) # Would be better to apply Explicit wait to click on `Απόρριψη`
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Απόρριψη')]").click()
nextbuttons = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ul[@class='pagination']/li[5]/a")
length = int(nextbuttons.get_attribute("innerText"))
for i in range(2,length+1):
    nextopt = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ul[@class='pagination']/li/a[contains(text(),'{}')]".format(i))
    nextopt.click()
    time.sleep(5)
```